# Image overflow:hidden with scale transition

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the effect where when you hover over an image, it zooms in the border. I'm trying to do this by having a CSS3 transition for scale on hover, with overflow: hidden on the image:

```
.portrait {
width: 20%;
overflow: hidden;
transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}
.portrait:hover {
transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

But the excess still shows when the image is hovered. How do I make this work?

Comment: you need to share the HTML for this section. is `portrait` the image ? or is the container for the image ? is the image set as `background-image` or as `img` tag ? please provide all the necessary details to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the image in a parent element, and use `overflow: hidden` on the parent.

```css
.portrait {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.portrait img {
  transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}

.portrait:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="portrait">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you scale the whole `.portrait`, not just the image.

There are 2 solutions:

#### The image is in `background-image`

Then you have to use `background-size` to scale your image up.

#### You have an `img` tag in `.portrait`

Just do this

```
.portrait:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Here is a little pen, using the second solution: https://codepen.io/math2001/pen/zZXBbj?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

I want to propose a more modern scss/css solution!

```css
/* SCSS Code */


/*
.scale-mask {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: $borderRadius;
    > img {
        transition: 0.4s;
        transform: scale(1.3);
        &:hover {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
}
*/


/* CSS Code */

.scale-mask {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 400px;
  /* Size */
  max-height: 400px;
  /* Size */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Centered horizontally */
}

.scale-mask>img {
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.scale-mask>img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="scale-mask">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/400x400/?city" alt="" />
</div>
```